# To get view object from UITableviewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have added a textfield in oe of the cell in my tableview.
Now I want to compare if the touched object is textfield or not. For that I am using -

```
  -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
    {
       UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    }
```

method. Here I have to get the view touched in UITableview cell is textfield.
How can I get that? I am struct at this. Please help.

Comment: Why do you want to get the touch in touchesBegan: method? Why not using outlet for textfield or delegate methods of uitextfield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if([[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
         UITextField *txtField = (UITextField *) [touch view];
         //UITextField object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use TextField Delegate method :

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to achieve this would be:

1. Create a `UITableViewCell` subclass with a `UITextField` as a subview. Define it as an `IBOutlet` and hook it up via interface builder.
2. Create a delegate protocol to notify a delegate (in your case it could be the same class handling the `UITableViewDataSource`) of this event.
3. Declare the `UITableViewCell` subclass as a `UITextFieldDelegate` and hook it up to the `UITextField` you've created. via IB
4. Implement

   -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField    {
      [self.delegate textFieldWasTapped];
   }

Now you'll be notified in the main controller of a `textFieldWasTapped` event. There's no need to check if it indeed came from a UITextField object because only instances if this type will be able to trigger this call.